# AudioManager.startBluetoothSco() crashes on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-5.0-lollipop

When making a call to [AudioManager.startBluetoothSCO()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#startBluetoothSco()) while targeting API level 18 or above in the Manifest, the documentation states that a raw audio connection is established, and if targeting API 17 or below a virtual voice call is used.

Up until API level 20 (Android L Preview) this worked fine, targeting any API. However, when using the latest Android Lollipop build LPX13D and targeting API level 18 or above I get a crash with the following stack trace:

E/AndroidRuntime(31705): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.getAddress()' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime(31705):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
E/AndroidRuntime(31705):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
E/AndroidRuntime(31705):    at android.media.IAudioService$Stub$Proxy.startBluetoothSco(IAudioService.java:1587)
E/AndroidRuntime(31705):    at android.media.AudioManager.startBluetoothSco(AudioManager.java:1468)

If I target API level 17 or below on Android Lollipop everything works as expected.

I believe the source of the problem lies in a change to Android's audio code that happened in API level 21 in the file AudioService.java line 2392:

```
public void startBluetoothSco(IBinder cb, int targetSdkVersion) {
    int scoAudioMode =
            (targetSdkVersion < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) ?
                    SCO_MODE_VIRTUAL_CALL : SCO_MODE_UNDEFINED;
    startBluetoothScoInt(cb, scoAudioMode);
}
```

It looks like SCO_MODE_UNDEFINED should instead be SCO_MODE_RAW. If you look through the file you can see that SCO_MODE_RAW is checked for in a few places, but is never actually passed in anywhere.

Is anybody else experiencing this crash? Does anyone know of a better fix than downgrading the target SDK to 17? If not, could you please star the [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78404) I filed with Google to increase the chance that it will be looked at :-)

Comment: Even if I don't get the crash, the device doesn't seem to route audio from the Bluetooth mic.

Comment: i have the same problem,mic is not routing,any solution for that?

Answer (score 4):

As @xsveda wrote if there is no headset connected, you will receive NPE on Lollipop.

You can try to check bluetooth headset connection first:

```
mAudioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn()
```

As doc described `isWiredHeadsetOn()` ([doc link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isWiredHeadsetOn())) is depricated and uses only to check is a headset is connected or not.

And after this you can use `startBluetoothSco()` connection. As for me I used this code:

This one for start:

```
if(mAudioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn())
    mAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
```

This one for stop:

```
if(mAudioManager.isBluetoothScoOn())
            mAudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

After few days of despair I've found a simple workaround:

`startBluetoothSco()` throws NPE only if there is no Bluetooth device connected so it can be caught and ignored as there is "no one to talk to". If i.e. a BT headset is connected, SCO is started successfully and playback is working!

Comment: That does seem like a better workaround than setting the target SDK to 17, however upon further investigation I noticed that with both workarounds audio is not routed through the bluetooth mic but instead goes out through the phone's mic. It's easy to miss this if you have your phone and bluetooth device near each other.

Answer (score 0):

For now what seems to work for me was ignoring the `NullPointerException`:

```
private void tryConnectAudio() {
    verifyBluetoothSupport();
    try {
        mAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // TODO This is a temp workaround for Lollipop
        Log.d(TAG, "startBluetoothSco() failed. no bluetooth device connected.");
    }
}
```

@Julian Claudino, This works for me and routing through the Bluetooth mic, make sure that the Bluetooth device is recognized and connected:

```
private void verifyBluetoothSupport() {
    getActivity().registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int state = intent.getIntExtra(AudioManager.EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE, -1);
            Log.d(TAG, "Audio SCO state: " + state);
            if (AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED == state) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Bluetooth Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                getActivity().unregisterReceiver(this);
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED));
}
```

Hope this helps someone !